# custom over-the-air android app installation

Tags: php, over-the-air

Help me in the following query if anyone has any idea about it: -

In over-the-app android app installation, User redirected to app store if clicked on download the app link. But I dont want my user to redirect to anywhere.

What I want is when user clicks on download app link on my website he should get a popup where he will sign in thorugh gmail , select mobile and agree to the permission , then app will automatically download on his mobile.

Comment: the update apk is in playstore or on your server ?

Comment: what's the query here ? if downloading passively from playstore is possible or not ?surely possible.  take a look at [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/)

Comment: I know its possible,  But I dont want user to redirect anywhere?? I want user can download the app from website without redirecting

Comment: yeah that link was about it i think. its unofficial, grab the source from there and integrate only the parts relevant in your own wrapper.

Comment: also take a look at this [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/wikis/HowDownloadApps.wiki)